# Can not finish dotnet ef migrations add using with MySQL and .NET 5.0. Error : Could not load file or assembly

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-migrations, .net-5

I'm trying to run dotnet ef database update InitDatabase from CLI.
I use MySQL Server 8.0.23 with Connector/NET 8.0
My project is in .NET 5.0 and I have installed the following Nuget packages :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="5.0.0-alpha.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.NetTopologySuite" Version="5.0.0-alpha.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have no trouble to create my migration, but when i want to update my MySql database, I meet the following issue :

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'

D:\TT\API\Pronostiques\TrashTalkPronostics.API.UI\TrashTalkPronostics.Core.Users.Infrastructures>dotnet ef database update InitDatabase
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TrashTalkPronostics.Core.Pronos.Data.Migrations, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
File name: 'TrashTalkPronostics.Core.Pronos.Data.Migrations, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, RuntimeAssembly assemblyContext, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsAssembly..ctor(ICurrentDbContext currentContext, IDbContextOptions options, IMigrationsIdGenerator idGenerator, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DesignTimeServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddDbContextDesignTimeServices>b__7(IServiceProvider _)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.EnsureServices(IServiceProvider services)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)


Could not load file or assembly 'TrashTalkPronostics.Core.Pronos.Data.Migrations, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
```

I was first using versions 3.2.4 for Pomelo packages, but the result was the same.
If someone has any clue to solve this problem, I would really appreciate help.

EDIT : I also tried to update the different EntityFrameworkCore nuget packages to version 5.0.5, with the same result

Answer (score 0):

As I was stuck for three days on this issue, I finally found how to fix it. I should have thought about it earlier.
I just copied the dll that was missing on my projetc and everything it ok